# Gnome: Let the current window be active while dragging another window's content.

Tags: linux, gnome3

I am long time windows user, recently I switched Arch with Gnome3. I often use mouse gestures to copy, move and other tasks. I really miss windows experience in Gnome. Like easily copy content from other window to current window, but in gnome when drag content from other window it get active  and current window get hidden behind the other active window.
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: You get used to this and just position source window so that it does not completely obscure target window. You also could play around with how windows get focus, but I haven't done this, for me this issue was not a big deal

Comment: @r0berts thanks for reply. I thought Linux is fully customizable.

Comment: It is, but sometimes you have to learn how; for this particular bit I haven't as I did not find it difficult to live with it and heaps of other stuff seemed more interesting. Why don't you go to gnome developers irc in addition to this?

Comment: @MdAdil `Linux is fully customizable` is obviously a relative statement. In many cases, that means `if you patch the source yourself`. Obviously no one desktop environment and/or window manager provides _every_ option anyone could ever dream up. Even highly configurable WMs might omit some you want. And wide-ranging DEs like GNOME aim for cohesive designs that tend to rule out offering 1000s of options. Course, if you can justify why some feature would be broadly beneficial & in line with the rest of the design, maybe it can get added. But you'd do that at the GNOME Bugzilla, not on SuperUser.

Comment: @underscore_d I just wanted to know there is such option or not..

Answer (score 0):

This should be configured in two places. Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and `dconf-editor` packages. Then:

1) Run gnome-tweak-tool, select "Windows" and set "Window focus mode" to "mouse".

2) Run dconf-editor, select org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.raise-on-click and set it to "False".

Then you will be able to have active window in background and copy from that some text to foreground window.